# Plotting the Differential Energy Spectrum from the Energy Spectrum

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I have the energy spectrum of a certain number of particles N(E) v/s E.

However, I want to plot the differential energy spectrum i.e. dN/dE v/s E.I DO NOT intend to calculate the derivative here [ as the traditional way of representing a differential energy spectrum might suggest ]  What I essentially need is the number of particles in the histogram to be divided by the bin-width.

Is there any way to do this automatically in matplotlib or something similar? Or do I actually need to do this manually, wherein I need to write some code to first put the particles in different bins and then divide by the bin-width and then redraw the histogram.

Comment: Matplotlib can plot data. It does not care about how to obtain the data. Now you are basically asking how to compute the derivative of a function. There are probably million ways of doing that, one of the more efficient ones can be to use numpy. I suggest, you have a look at [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and if you have a specific question, provide a [MCVE] for it.

Comment: Umm...No. That's a wrong interpretation of my question. I do not intend to calculate the derivative of my function [in fact there is no function. I just have a distribution over a variable(E)]. If you read the 2nd paragraph of the 2nd line, as I explain, I now just intend to obtain the differential spectrum wherein each y-value is divided by the bin-width

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib is a graphical library. it can plot data and edit figures.

What you need to do there is apply a numerical method to differentiate your data. It shouldnt be difficult.

You could just apply the definition of the derivative, having as DeltaT the shortest measurement you got of E

Once you got the data you can just use matplotlib to plot it.

if you post the data here i would glady give you an example of how to do it.

or you can just check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Comment: My question was whether I have to write my own code or there is some inherent feature in matplotlib/numpy etc. It seems I have to write my own. Thanks!